# Inequality holds?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, inequality

Can anyone prove that
$$
\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k*} a_i i (x+\epsilon)^{(i-1)}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k*} a_i (x+\epsilon)^{i}+k^*-1}>\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k*} a_i i x^{(i-1)}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k*} a_i x^{i}+k^*-1}
$$
where $a_i$ are some positive coefficients, $\epsilon$ is a positive number and $0<x<1$?

Comment: Why do you think this is true? Is there any evidence?

Comment: False in general.  For example when $k^*=1$.

Comment: is that fctn $\frac 1 x$ when k* =  1 ? isn' t it positive near 0 and 0 at $\infty$ ?

Comment: sorry the sums should go from $1$ to $k^*-1$ not to $k^*$. I wrote the question from another computer.
@Davide Giraudo yes $g$ is a decreasing function according to your definition and left side should be also decreasing but according to this, how can we conclude that left side is greater than the right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the reversed inequality which is true: let $f(x):=\sum_{i=1}a_ix^i$, and define $g(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)+k^*-1}=\frac{d}{dx}(\ln f(x))$. Then $g'(x)=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\ln f(x))$, and since $f$ is increasing, and $\log$ is concave, $x\mapsto \ln f(x)$ is concave, so $g'\leq 0$ and $g$ is decreasing.

Comment: yes your prove is correct and so nice. Thank you very much.